# subscriber list of a pusub node in xmpp

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I want list of all the subscribers (jid of subscribers) who are subscribed to my pubsub node.I am using strophe.js.

I have done it.but its not working properly:-

```
 $iq({to: service, type: "get"})
        .c('pubsub', {xmlns: NS_PUBSUB})
        .c('subscriptions', {node: node})
```

Plz do help me out...

Comment: How does it not work? Unless you show the stanzas and responses, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your access model, (see http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#accessmodels), you may have to send your iq using the pubsub owner namespace.

```
$iq({to: service, type:"get"})
  .c('pubsub', {xmlns: Strophe.NS.PUBSUB_OWNER})
  .c('subscriptions', {node: node});
```